# What are some specific benefits of having my name as a coauthor on a research paper as an undergrad?

Tags: publications, mathematics, authorship, undergraduate

I'm finishing up my B.S. in mathematics right now, and I was approached by a former professor with whom I've kept a good relationship, and she asked if I would be able/willing to help her and another professor in a research project they are working on.

My role is pretty purely computational, basically just implementing their mathematical work in code, but she said that it's enough to have me listed as a coauthor on the paper, considering that things don't go south (which, they aren't expected to).

Besides having Erdos number 4 (hey, pretty good for a fresh bachelor's degree), are there some actual benefits that would go along with having my name on a publication?

Just to be clear, this is *not* an undergrad research opportunity or project, nor do I think(?) it is [considered a graduate paper](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16879/in-what-ways-would-co-authoring-a-graduate-research-paper-as-an-undergraduate-he). They are both published professors working on this as a team.

Could this help me get into a better grad school (rather-- master's program) than I would otherwise be able to (pretty average GPA, to be honest)? Help secure some funding? etc

Comment: In a word, yes. Contributing to an actual research paper, and getting a mentor to say good things in a recommendation letter about your role in the project, is the single best thing you can do for your grad school application.

Comment: I think what you're asking is the same as (the first part) of the other question.  "graduate level" research paper just means (to me) not "undergraduate level."  (not that there's a clear cut difference)

Comment: Ah. I just figured it meant PhD research, but probably you're right

Comment: @user37208: I have to disagree with your comment.  Having some research under your belt certainly counts positively, but just having your name on a paper -- especially one coauthored with faculty members who will not be able to point to critical intellectual contributions made by the student -- need not be a game-changer.  The single best thing a math graduate applicant can do is to have taken the right array of challenging courses (including courses which cover graduate level material) and to have performed excellently in these courses -- ideally, compared to actual graduate students.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I take issue with your use of the phrase "just having your name on a paper" -- presumably the student will have their name on the paper for a _reason_. It's the work they did that is (or isn't) the game-changer, not the name on the paper.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Would you say, however, that non-baby research experience is one of the best ways for an applicant to distinguish themselves from the large pack of students who earned good grades in challenging coursework?

Comment: @DanRomik: Unfortunately in my experience a common "reason" an undergraduate student's name is on a paper is that nowadays undergraduate research in mathematics needs to result in publications in order for the research programs to stay competitive for funding.  In most cases the student *did work* on the paper, but a different student who took up the same research project would have been guided to the same work.  I have never met an undergraduate student who did truly meaningful research and did not excel in their coursework.

Comment: ... The bottom line is that we don't admit students primarily on the basis of the recommendation letters from their research experiences...which are invariably glowing.

Comment: @user37208: I don't think there is a large pack of students who earned excellent grades in truly challenging coursework, so doing this -- in confluence with strong test scores, which is more like checking that the coursework was for real -- really is enough to get into great programs.  For instance, when I applied to math PhD programs I had no papers (published, submitted or in preparation) but I was on my way to a four year BA/MS at my strong undergraduate institution.  I applied to five PhD programs in mathematics and got into all of them, including the top three in the US.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I did mention in the post that this isn't an undergraduate research opportunity.  EDIT -- semantically, I am an undergrad, and this is an opportunity for research -- so that's not so clear ;)  What I mean is that it's not something like an undergrad research project sponsored for school credit that they offer to anyone. (I'm at KSU, btw -- I noticed you're at UGA. One of the authors got his PhD there)

Comment: @jaska: I saw that you mentioned that the work didn't take place in the context of an REU.  But it is still research done by an undergraduate and coauthored by faculty members.  As someone who spent several years doing admissions in my math graduate program, I would have evaluated the situation in roughly the same way: it's definitely nice, but in order to change the situation I need to hear from the faculty coauthor that your contribution was crucial.  I also noticed that you don't describe it that way in your question: rather you say that you mostly wrote code to implement their math.

Comment: I'm not trying to denigrate your work or be discouraging, by the way.  That you understood the math and had the programming skills to contribute usefully to a project is a real plus.  It's just that -- in my own direct experience, anyway -- that is not *the most important part* of your application.

Answer (score 5):

> Could this help me get into a better grad school (rather-- master's
>   program) than I would otherwise be able to (pretty average GPA, to be
>   honest)? Help secure some funding? etc

Yes, it can help you with all those things and more (including non-academia-related things like applying for a job in industry). Generally speaking, being a coauthor of a published paper in mathematics says good things about you and your math/STEM/academic/research abilities in any context in which someone would care about those abilities.

However, it's important to take things in perspective and understand that "just" the fact of your being a coauthor on a single paper will not make a huge difference in and of itself. E.g., a grad school or fellowship candidate with no publications can easily "beat" a candidate who has a publication if the former has other good things going for them (a better GPA, better recommendations etc) that the latter doesn't. What I would say matters a lot more is not just being a coauthor, but **what you actually did to deserve being a coauthor**. If you do an unusually good job on the project, this can translate to excellent recommendations, which will carry a far greater weight in a grad school application than the mere coauthorship line on your CV. If you were just a code monkey who did low quality work, the coauthorship would still be of some value but would overall not be worth very much.

Finally, I should mention that you seem to think that work that's "pretty purely computational" is less important or creative than other sorts of math research, but that is not universally true (although it may be true in specific instances). Even in a computational project there may still be a lot of room for creativity, and a chance to excel in all kinds of unexpected ways. Who knows, you may end up having an idea for a cool optimization that would extend the computational range of the algorithm enough to enable you to discover an amazing new phenomenon your collaborators did not even suspect existed (such things have happened many times). Besides, understanding complicated mathematical constructions well enough to translate them into code can be a highly nontrivial challenge. You would also get to experience the thrill of doing mathematical research and taking a part in the discovery of new knowledge, learn about working collaboratively with others, and probably derive many other benefits from the experience. So, to summarize, I would not scoff at the opportunity to take part in such a project. Doing it just for the paper coauthorship would probably be a bad idea, but doing it for the experience and knowledge you will gain, *plus* the chance of a coauthorship, seem like excellent reasons to me.

Comment: I agree 100% with this, by the way.